# Installing development tools packages error Centos 6.6

Tags: centos6, yum, packages, dependencies

I'm trying to install `curl-devel` package as a prior step to installation of git 2.x.x:

```
 yum install curl-devel
```

But I get many errors like this one:

```
Error: Package: gcc-c++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5)
               libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6
               libstdc++ = 4.4.7-4.el6
           Updated By: libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libstdc++ = 4.4.7-16.el6
               libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6
           Removing: libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6
               libstdc++ = 4.4.7-11.el6
           Updated By: libstdc++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libstdc++ = 4.4.7-16.el6
               libstdc++ = 4.4.4-15.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

I don't know what this error is about. Can someone explain and suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Update the system first.

Comment: @I have updated the system. I appreciate any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command -:

```
yum install curl-devel --skip-broken 

or 

yum install gcc*  

then 

yum install curl-devel
```

Comment: `yum install gcc*` did not work for me

Comment: @Ok please try this command -:
       yum install curl-devel --skip-broken
 when u try yum install gcc* then what output please send me,